# Using GPIOs from the C232HM FTDI

Tags: ftdi

I've been reading this [document](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_135_MPSSE_Basics.pdf) in order to check if it is possible to use both the serial communication of the FTDI chip and also control the GPIOs. I'm still unsure whether or not I'd need to control them simultaneously. From the aforementioned document there is some code to control the GPIOs, however I am still uncertain how to program the chip. What IDE should I use etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  In addition to the document mentioned:

[AN 135 MPSSE Basics](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_135_MPSSE_Basics.pdf)

See also the following document which lists the commands that can be sent to the engine.

[AN 108 command Processor for MPSSE and MCU Host Bus Emulation Modes](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_108_Command_Processor_for_MPSSE_and_MCU_Host_Bus_Emulation_Modes.pdf)

In particular the section `3.6 Set / Read Data Bits High / Low Bytes`.

Comment: Hi Mark thank you for this. How can I send the commands though? Over a serial terminal or so?

Comment: @Luke The first document has the links to the device drivers and D2XX C library and has example code in C.

Comment: Hi Mark I saw those, so I'm assuming that I can't use the GPIOs and serial pins simultaneously? Or I need to program it to do so?

Comment: @Luke The D2XX APIs give you control to implement any protocol you would like (SPI, I2C, JTAG, etc).  You can bit bang all bits of the port directly (you manage the rise and fall of every signal), or use commands to shift data over the serial connections.  There are examples in the document.